# Почему не отображается Fragment во ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Есть активити в нем через ViewPager отображаются статьи. Внутри ViewPager фрагменты. Проблема в том что фрагменты не отображаются, не могу понять почему((

ArticleActivity.java

```
public class ArticleActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private int articleOrderNumber;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);

        pagerAdapter = new ArticleActivityPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getArticles().size());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(articleOrderNumber - 1);

   }
}
```

activity_article.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context=".ArticleActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src = "@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="left"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menuButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/pocke_ball"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src = "@drawable/forward"
    android:text="next" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/menuButton"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>
```

ArticleActivityPagerAdapter.java

```
    public class ArticleActivityPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int countOfArticles;

    public ArticleActivityPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int countOfArticles) {
        super(fm);
        this.countOfArticles = countOfArticles;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countOfArticles;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArticleFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

ArticleFragment.java

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

    int articleOrderNumber;

    public static ArticleFragment newInstance(int page) {
        ArticleFragment fragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(Article.ORDER_NUMBER, page + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        articleOrderNumber = getArguments().getInt(Article.ORDER_NUMBER);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.article_fragment, container, false);
        ArticleRepository articles = ((MyApplication) activity.getApplication()).getArticles();
        Article article = articles.getByOrderNumber(articleOrderNumber);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
        RecyclerView recView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.articleRecView);
        recView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recView.setAdapter(new ArticleRecViewAdapter(article, activity));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

article_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ArticleFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/articleRecView" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: а сам Viewpager отображается?

Comment: @metalurgus да, все листается, фрагмент создается, и заполняется инфой(все методы oncreate, onStart и т д выполняются)

Comment: покажите, чтоли, XML самого фрагмента (`R.layout.article_fragment`)

Comment: @metalurgus, готово)

Comment: попробуйте поиграться с `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` - выставить его в `match_parent` в разных местах

Comment: @metalurgus, пробовал не помогло, но попробую еще, вдруг что упустил

Answer (score 1):

В ваших приведённых разметках все высоты и ширина должны быть во весь экран, т.е. `match_parent`

Comment: не помогло(( http://pastebin.com/2RZennHP

Comment: @JJoe, у меня ссылка не работает

Comment: обновил файлы в вопросе